Appium - App is not launching in the emulator
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Enums;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace AppiumClient
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> _driver;


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var appPath = @"C:\APKs\UAT_release.apk";

            //Platform,Device,Application
            var driverOption = new AppiumOptions();
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "sdk_gphone");
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, appPath);
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AppiumVersion, "11");
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverExecutable",    @"C:\Users\TestAutomation\AppiumClient\Drivers\chromedriver.exe");

            _driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"),    driverOption);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);


            while (_driver.FindElements(MobileBy.XPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button']   [2]")).Count() > 0)
            {
                _driver.FindElement(MobileBy.XPath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]")).Click();
            } 
                          _driver.FindElementById("uat:id/username").SendKeys("333");
                _driver.FindElementById("cuat:id/password").SendKeys("333);
                _driver.FindElementById("uat:id/signin").Click();
        }
    }
}




I am testing an apk using Appium. Using the above test script, test is not passing unless app is opened. But, I need test to be launch the app. Please let me know what can I do for this issue.
Appium - 2.5.2
